# Reading .mat files from Java

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I am using jmatio to read in a 10000x3072 array from a Matlab file (CIFAR10 dataset).

Here is what I have so far:

```
import com.jmatio.io.*;
import com.jmatio.types.*;

public class Driver {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    MatFileReader matfilereader = new MatFileReader("test_batch.mat");
    MLArray mlArrayRetrieved = matfilereader.getMLArray("data");
    System.out.println(mlArrayRetrieved);
    System.out.println(mlArrayRetrieved.contentToString());
  }
}
```

This is my output:

data = Cannot display variables with more than 1000 elements.

I tried iterating through the MLArray, but i get the following error:

```
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
```

Any ideas how I can print the array to the Console?

Answer (score 0):

change your way of access

MLArray details:
[http://intra.csb.ethz.ch/javadoc/metabolic/com/jmatio/io/MatFileReader.html#getMLArray(java.lang.String)](http://intra.csb.ethz.ch/javadoc/metabolic/com/jmatio/io/MatFileReader.html#getMLArray%28java.lang.String%29)

check this out too for how mlarray is implemented and then derive your method of access:
http://intra.csb.ethz.ch/javadoc/metabolic/src-html/com/jmatio/types/MLArray.html#line.306

Comment: Thanks for your response! What should I change it to? I can't use getIndex direction on the MLArray (its protected)

Comment: what happens when you use `mlarrayretrieve.toString()` instead ofcontentToString, does it give the more than 1000 elements error? And please post the actual output that you get on your console(the errors that is including the stacktrace and line numbers etc)

Comment: I used the above code on a smaller portion of the data set and it worked fine. I ended up converting everything the data to csv format from matlab and passed that into Java (much easier). Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can cast MLArray to MLDouble and then use the getArray() method which will give you a double[][]

```
MatFileReader matfilereader = new MatFileReader("test_batch.mat");
double[][] mlArrayDouble = ((MLDouble) matfilereader.getMLArray("data")).getArray();
```